# Why does Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector()) take so long?

Tags: .net, windows, wifi

I would like to establish a wifi connection by code now.

I am using the following function:

Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector())

It does work: It lists all available networks. The first results arrive after around 2-3 seconds, but some arrive only later (like 30 seconds later).

The one that I connect my laptop to has the best Rssi dBm value, but it appears only after like 30 seconds.

When I start up my laptop, it will connect to the Wifi very quickly, so I wonder why FindAllAsync is so slow and if there is a faster way to find wifis.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with the event approach (DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher) at least the discovery is fully/1by1 async? There's a full sample that you can test here: https://github.com/smourier/DeviceExplorer that uses this API

Comment: @SimonMourier Does it detect Wifis? I have tried it, and it detected my wifi adapter, but not wifis to connect with.